# Check if a string contains "-" and "]" at the same time

Tags: bash

I have the next two regex in Bash:

```
1.^[-a-zA-Z0-9\,\.\;\:]*$
2.^[]a-zA-Z0-9\,\.\;\:]*$
```

The first matches when the string contains a "-" and the other values.
The second when contains a "]".
I put this values at the beginning of my regex because I can't scape them.
How I can get match the two values at the same time?

Comment: For my grep it seems to work if you put the `-` right before the closing square bracket `...\:-]` (of the 2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also place the `-` at the *end* of the bracket expression, since a range must be closed on both ends.

```
^[]a-zA-Z0-9,.;:-]*$
```

You don't have to escape any of the other characters, either. Colons, semicolons, and commas have no special meaning in any part of a regular expression, and while a period loses its special meaning inside a bracket expression.

Comment: This would also match 'aaaa' which doesn't contain either `]` nor `-`

Comment: So would both of the original regular expressions; I'm just answering how to include both `]` and `-` inside the same bracket expression.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use this:

```
grep -E '^.*\-.*\[|\[.*\-.*$'
```

It matches either a `-` followed by zero or more arbitrary chars and a `[` or a `[` followed by zero or more chars and a `-`

However since you don't accept arbitrary chars, you need to change it to:

```
grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9,.;:]*\-[a-zA-Z0-9,.;:]*\[|\[[a-zA-Z0-9,.;:]*\-[a-zA-Z0-9,.;:]*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this can help you

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
echo $p | grep -E '\-.*\]|\].*\-' | grep "^[]a-zA-Z0-9,.;:-]*$"
done <$1

user-host:/tmp$ cat test
-i]string
]adfadfa-
string-
]string
str]ing
]123string
123string-
?????
++++++


user-host:/tmp$ ./test.sh test
-i]string
]adfadfa-
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions in your post.

1. One is in the description:

   > How I can get match the two values at the same time?

   That is an `OR` match, which could be done with a range that mix your two ranges:

   ```
   pattern='^[]a-zA-Z0-9,.;:-]*$'
   ```

   That will match a line that either contains one (or several) `-`…`OR`…`]`…`OR` any of the included characters. That would be all the lines (except `?????`, `++++++` and `as df gh`) in the test script below.
2. Two is in the title:

   > … a string contains “-” and “]” at the same time

   That is an `AND` match. The simplest (and slowest) way to do it is:

   ```
   echo "$line"  |  grep '-'  |  grep ']'   |  grep '^[-a-zA-Z0-9,.;:]*$'
   ```

   The first two calls to grep select **only** the lines that:

   contain both (one or several) `-` and (one or several) `]`

Test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

printlines(){
cat <<-\_test_lines_
asdfgh
asdfgh-
asdfgh]
as]df
as,df
as.df
as;df
as:df
as-df
as]]]df
as---df
asAS]]]DFdf
as123--456DF
as,.;:-df
as-dfg]h
as]dfg-h
a]s]d]f]g]h
a]s]d]f]g]h-
s-t-r-i-n-g]
as]df-gh
123]asdefgh
123asd-fgh-
?????
++++++
as df gh
_test_lines_
}

pattern='^[]a-zA-Z0-9,.;:-]*$'

printf '%s\n' "Testing the simple pattern of $pattern"
while read line; do
    resultgrep="$(  echo "$line" | grep "$pattern"  )"
    printf '%13s %-13s\n' "$line" "$resultgrep"
done < <(printlines)
echo "#############################################################"
echo

p1='-'; p2=']'; p3='^[]a-zA-Z0-9,.;:-]*$'

printf '%s\n' "Testing a 'grep AND' of '$p1', '$p2' and  '$p3'."
while read line; do
    resultgrep="$(  echo "$line" | grep "$p1" | grep "$p2" | grep "$p3"  )"
    [[ $resultgrep ]] && printf '%13s %-13s\n' "$line" "$resultgrep"
done < <(printlines)
echo "#############################################################"
echo

printf '%s\n' "Testing an 'AWK AND' of '$p1', '$p2' and  '$p3'."
while read line; do
    resultawk="$(  echo "$line" | 
    awk -v p1="$p1" -v p2="$p2" -v p3="$p3" '$0~p1 && $0~p2 && $0~p3' )"
    [[ $resultawk ]] && printf '%13s %-13s\n' "$line" "$resultawk"
done < <(printlines)
echo "#############################################################"
echo

printf '%s\n' "Testing a 'bash AND' of '$p1', '$p2' and  '$p3'."
while read line; do
    rgrep="$(  echo "$line" | grep "$p1" | grep "$p2" | grep "$p3"  )"
    [[ ( $line =~ $p1 ) && ( $line =~ $p2 ) && ( $line =~ $p3 ) ]]
    rbash=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    [[ $rbash ]] && printf '%13s %-13s %-13s\n' "$line" "$rgrep" "$rbash"
done < <(printlines)
echo "#############################################################"
echo
```